# Is there a "conventional" method of preventing nickname highlighting

Tags: irc

Every once and a while I want to mention someone without bothering them.  I usually use `nick/name` or something similar to convey the name without triggering a notification by their client.  Is there a conventional way to do this or do you usually just write out the name.

Answer (score 1):

I know of no mechanism to do this. After all it's really up to the user's client whether they want to be notified or not.

The only way to work around it is what you're already doing and somehow break the word so that the client notification won't catch it.

And after all if it having a client notification really annoys someone they can always turn it off in their client.